# Strange behavior of Math.round() method

Tags: java, math, jvm, rounding

I noticed an incomprehensible thing for me in static method [round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) in class [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

```
Math.round(0.4999999999999999);  // is 0
Math.round(0.49999999999999999); // is 1
```

Why?

Comment: @dystroy: This doesn't look like a bug to me. It looks like the OP is really rounding 0.5. (Note that the final digit is 9, not 4.)

Comment: It's not a duplicate and it's not a bug. It's how floating point numbers are behaving.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. I've read it too fast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`0.49999999999999999` has too many significant digits and one `double` variable cannot store them all. So implicit rounding happens during *compilation*. By the time you are calling `Math.round()`, the argument is already 0.5 (check yourself: `0.49999999999999999 == 0.5` yields `true`).